# How to add custom logo, social media, contact us, local business schema in joomla, virtuemart?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, virtuemart

I need to add below listed schema tags in my website, developed in joomla virtuemart.

Is there a way to add these schema tags dynamically?

My code example...

```
Logo schema – Home Page
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.domainname.com/",
  "logo": "http://www.domainname.com/images/logo.png"
}


Socail Media Schema - 

<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.domainname.com/">
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.facebook.com/PageName/">FB</a>
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://twitter.com/PageName">Twitter</a>
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.instagram.com/PageName/">Instagram</a>
</span>


 Contact Us Schema

{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.domainname.com",
  "contactPoint": [
    { "@type": "ContactPoint",
      "telephone": "+91 10000 10000",
      "contactType": "customer service"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please reply

Thanks

Comment: Do you "really" need to this.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend **Google Structured Data** plugin from Tassos Marinos.  It has most of the major structured data types and he releases a new update with more about every month.  I use it on all my sites.
 
https://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/google-structured-data-markup

Answer (score 0):

Joomla gives you structured data automatically (such as in the built in contact form) and has APIs to do more if you need it. That's why you use a CMS, so that it takes care of those things rather than you having to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it does, but it is not as per our requirement.

Comment: So just modify it using the API.  You can gt more details over on the [joomla.se] stack exchange site.